# Spring Security MockMVC with @WithMockUser() always returns Successful status

Tags: spring, spring-security, mocking, mockmvc

I am trying to test some endpoints (I am quite new to testing) and having an issue where the Mocked Authentication seems to always be accepted and returns a 200.

The test without Auth seems to have a user with just a ROLE_USER but the endpoint still returns a success.

I can only assume my SecurityConfig is not being used by the MockMVC instance and a default "let all requests happen" is?

Even changing my Security Config to only allow users with "ROLE_GOD" still results in status.OK for all test requests.

Tried following the Spring Docs and some posts on here and not getting any luck...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
DataController.getIndex org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@ca25360: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@36ebcb: Username: user; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER
```

```
Expected :CLIENT_ERROR
Actual   :SUCCESSFUL
```

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class DataControllerTest {

    @LocalServerPort
    private int port;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    @Before
    public void before() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.webApplicationContext)
                .apply(springSecurity())
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    @WithMockUser(roles = {"ADMIN"}, setupBefore = TestExecutionEvent.TEST_METHOD)
    public void getRequest() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("!!!" + SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication());
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("http://localhost:" + port)).andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().is2xxSuccessful())
                .andExpect(content().string("HELLO!"));
    }

    @Test
    @WithMockUser(setupBefore = TestExecutionEvent.TEST_METHOD)
    public void getRequestWithoutAuth() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("!!!" + SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication());
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("http://localhost:" + port)).andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().is4xxClientError());
    }

}
```

My SecurityConfig:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        super.configure(auth);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.cors().disable().csrf().disable()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .and()
                .formLogin().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.
I am an idiot.

My URIs were not correct in the Test classes MockMVC.perform().

```
 @Test
    @WithMockUser(roles = {"ADMIN"}, setupBefore = TestExecutionEvent.TEST_METHOD)
    public void getRequest() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("!!!" + SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication());
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("http://localhost:" + port+"/")).andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().is2xxSuccessful())
                .andExpect(content().string("HELLO!"));
    }

    @Test
    @WithMockUser(setupBefore = TestExecutionEvent.TEST_METHOD)
    public void getRequestWithoutAuth() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("!!!" + SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication());
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("http://localhost:" + port+"/")).andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().is4xxClientError());
    }
```

The URIs needed the / following the port argument.

```
CORRECT : http://localhost:9999/
INCORRECT : http://localhost:9999
```